# react-native: back button in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to have back button on all of my tabs in my drawer navigator (except the home page). I am using react-navigation.

I tried doing this like in the react-navigation docs...

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ //open School instagram
            top: 9,
            left: -99,
        }}
            onPress={() => { () => goBack(null) }}>
            <Image
            style={{

                height: 33,
                width: 33,
                tintColor: '#E1B60B',
            }}
            source={require('../resources/icons/homeb.png')}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

However this just always went back to the home screen for me, even when I went to other screens prior.
I also had some formatting issues with this component. It would always go to the top of the screen and leave a white bar (even with absolute positioning).

Here is the code for my drawer navigator:

```
export const Root = DrawerNavigator({

  Home: { screen: Home },
  About: { screen: About },
  Administration: { screen: Administration },
  CSF: { screen: CSF },
  Calendar: { screen: Calendar },
  Directory: { screen: Directory },
  HNN: { screen: HNN },
  NHS: {screen: NHS},
  IB: { screen: IB },
  ID: { screen: ID },
  Site: { screen: Site },
  WebStore: { screen: WebStore },


}, {
  // drawer config
  //drawerWidth: 239, //drawer width //auto size for device

  contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>, //scrolling drawer
  //backBehavior: 'none', //currently makes back button do nothing
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  drawerBackgroundColor: 'whitesmoke',
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen', //stuff that prevents errors
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',  //stuff that prevents errors
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle', //stuff that prevents errors
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#63461E', //brown active text
    inactiveTintColor: '#7F6D45', //light brown inactive text
    style: {
      marginVertical: 9,

    }
  }
  //end drawer config
});
```

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Could you post a little more of your code? What looks like your `goBack()` method ? How are you navigating between pages ?

Comment: The go back method is built into react-navigation, which is what I am using.

Comment: @JimmyJohnJones i had to delete my answer, no time right now to write more. Have a look on nested navigators, this is how you are going to overcome the problem. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting